# Configuration.GetSection(); returning null in Console App .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have a console app and trying to get my connection string using the configurator but this is always returning a null value,this is working perfectly fine when using `IConfigurator` in the Web API project, please see below, is there something I'm missing in the console?

Console `Program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                builder.Sources.Clear();
                var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
                var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
                builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                 .AddJsonFile($"version.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                // connection strings mysql
                var myConnection = context.Configuration.GetSection("myConnection").Value; //null returned here
                // rest of the logic...
            });
    }

    return hostBuiler;
}
```

`appsettings.development.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myConnection": "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=Student;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"
  }
}
```

Web API project `Program.cs`:

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var myConnection = configuration.GetSection("myConnection").Value; //value returned here

    services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseMySql(myConnection, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(myConnection)));  

    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `GetSection`, but you're providing a value key, not a section.

You can call `GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["myConnection"]`, or, alternatively use the built in extension method `GetConnectionString("myConnection")` 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring

```cs
var myConnection = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnection");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get connection string the you can use [`GetConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

> Calling this method is shorthand for `GetSection("ConnectionStrings")[name]`.

```cs
var myConnection = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnection");
```

Answer (score 0):

Console app was missing launchSettings.json,so i had to provide environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to know which environment it's pointing to,which was local.